# How to specify a variable in JuMP that can only be 0 or 1?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

What is the syntax for specifying a variable in a JuMP optimization problem that can only be 0 or 1?

I am using the following code:

```
@variable(mod, X == 1 || 0)
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write:

```
@variable(mod, x, Bin)
```

You might also want to checkout the the [documentation](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/variables/#Binary-(ZeroOne)-constraints-1) for more examples.